# Store/load registers in descending order in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

Let's say we have 8 32-bit registers `{r5-r12}` that contain arbitrary values and `r0` that contains a memory address.

I want to store `r12` in `[r0]`, `r11` in `[r0, #4]`, ..., `r5` in `[r0, #28]`.

In this case using the instruction `stm` is not possible as the registers should be given in ascending order.

It can be done by using 8 `str` instructions, but I am wondering if it would be possible to do something more efficient (in terms of code size and clock cycles)?

Comment: you probably want to at least do pairs of registers, the cost of the store is possibly worse than moving registers around so once you clear up a pair for example write r12 and r11 then mov r9 and r10 then strd or stm.  if your bus is 32 bits wide then no gain if it is 64 bits wide then you will save clocks, depending on the core the fetches may be single transactions of 4 or 8 instructions at a time so minimal overhead.  what core is this what does your path to memory look like, etc

Comment: If possible, try to change the preceding code such that the values end up in r5 to r12 in opposite order.

Comment: wait what about stmdb?, naw maybe strd, can it decrement as well as increment? and I never can remember if it swaps them or not (biggest number register goes in the lowest address).  Even if it cant do strd r12,r0,#-8 you can still do the subtraction separately and it will execute fast while the prior store is still going on.

Comment: @old_timer `wait what about stmdb`: it can't help in this case. Highest numbered register will be stored at the highest memory address and the lowest number register will be stored at the lowest memory address not dependent on IA/DB mode.

Comment: yep was thinking out loud